# Linear parametric system of 5 equations and 4 unknowns

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

$$\text{Let} \ \  A= \left[
    \begin{array}{cccc}
      2&-1&3&4\\
      2&c&0&6\\
      -2&1&c-5&-4\\ 
      2&c&0&c+5\\
      0&c+1&c-5&2
    \end{array}
\right], \ \ \ 
  b = \left[
      \begin{array}{c}
      1\\
      1\\
      -1\\ 
      2\\
      0
    \end{array}
\right], \ \ \text{and} \ \ 
X = \left[
      \begin{array}{c}
      x\\
      y\\
      z\\ 
      w
    \end{array}
\right]
 $$

Determine all values of c for which the system $AX = b$ has

(i) no solution,

(ii) infinitely many solutions,

(iii) unique solution.

Write the solutions in cases (ii) and (iii).

Firstly, I have written it as an augmented matrix.

After that I have tried to find echelon form. I got one bad row.

So can't solve this question. Please help me.

Comment: Is your $A$ missing a column?

Comment: @Moo I have added PICUTRE. Please check

Comment: @dxiv I have updated ( added picture)

Comment: @Moo What is incorrect here?

Comment: @user311726 Better than the picture, fix the $X$ in your posted question. As for the problem itself, one hint is that row $5$ of $A$ is the sum of row $2$ and row $3$.

Comment: @Moo How did you get this answer ?

Comment: @Moo Can you explain ?

Comment: @Moo I cannot get first row exact yours